# Setting up Coldfusion 10 with IIS - Unable to configure IIS connector

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to setup Coldfusion to work with IIS on my Windows 8 laptop. I have installed the ISAP filter and extensions along with the CGI extension but when I run the wsconfig and add the web server it then throws the error "Unable to configure IIS Connector". What can I try next? I've made sure they're all enabled in the IIS manager also.

Comment: Are you running wsconfig as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I am ....................

Comment: I seem to remember something about II6 scripting host or something has to be installed too.

Comment: Did you try running {coldfusion root}\cfusion\bin\connectors\Upgrade_all_connectors.bat in an a Command Prompt (run as administrator)?  You shouldn't need the IIS 6 stuff unless you are attempting to install CF 9.x or earlier.

Comment: I just ran that and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Just went back to run it again and noticed it was erroring before exiting and it says "There are no configured web servers"

Comment: Please anyone? This would be hugely appreciated if someone can put this problem to rest :(

Comment: I too had the same issue; but then did a manual config to resolve it. http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion10-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The coldfusion 8 webserver configuration tool states that it is compatible until IIS 7. This is probably why it fails to add the handler mappings for IIS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by uninstalling coldfusion and re installing worked, that way in the setup it was able to identify what web servers were currently running and give me the option to configure coldfusion with IIS. Hope this helps someone else too